# Global list mutation inside function in Python

Tags: python

I am working on a backtracking solution for this problem - "Given a string s, partition s such that every substring of the partition is a palindrome."

I have written this code where I am not able to get **how is the global 2D list strings is getting updated?** What exactly is happening here? I tried using global keyword too with it inside palinBreak function, but it doesn't help! **When should global keyword be used?**

**Observation:** Every element of global list strings changes to local list variable arr. For instance, strings = [x, y] and arr = [z], then strings becomes [z, z, z]; whereas I want it to be [x, y, z]. Why does this happen?

**EDIT: Adding expected output** vs. output I am getting (take notice from line 3 onwards).

Expected output is:

```
ans is ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'] []
strings is [['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b']]
ans is ['a', 'b', 'aa', 'b'] [['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b']]
strings is [['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'aa', 'b']]
ans is ['a', 'baab'] [['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'aa', 'b']]
strings is [['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'aa', 'b'], ['a', 'baab']]
ans is ['aba', 'a', 'b'] [['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'aa', 'b'], ['a', 'baab']]
strings is [['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'aa', 'b'], ['a', 'baab'], ['aba', 'a', 'b']]
[['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'aa', 'b'], ['a', 'baab'], ['aba', 'a', 'b']]
```

Output:

```
ans is ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'] []
strings is [['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b']]
ans is ['a', 'b', 'aa', 'b'] [['a', 'b', 'aa', 'b']]
strings is [['a', 'b', 'aa', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'aa', 'b']]
ans is ['a', 'baab'] [['a', 'baab'], ['a', 'baab']]
strings is [['a', 'baab'], ['a', 'baab'], ['a', 'baab']]
ans is ['aba', 'a', 'b'] [['aba', 'a', 'b'], ['aba', 'a', 'b'], ['aba', 'a', 'b']]
strings is [['aba', 'a', 'b'], ['aba', 'a', 'b'], ['aba', 'a', 'b'], ['aba', 'a', 'b']]
[[], [], [], []]
>>>
```

Code:

```
def isPalin(s):
    i = 0
    j = len(s)-1
    while(i<j):
        if(s[i]!=s[j]):
            return False
        i+=1
        j-=1
    return True

def palinBreak(s, start, arr):
    #print "Called", start, arr
    #global strings
    if(start==len(s)):
        print "ans is", arr, strings
        strings.append(arr)
        print "strings is", strings
        return 0

    flag = -1
    for i in range(1, len(s)-start+1):
        curr = s[start : start+i]
        #print "Testing curr and start and i", curr, start, i
        if(isPalin(curr)):
            arr.append(curr)
            #print arr, start, i
            #print "Next call from", start+i
            pb = palinBreak(s, start+i, arr)
            if(pb != -1):
                flag = 1
            arr.pop()
            #print "popped l", arr
    return flag

strings = []
palinBreak("abaab", 0, [])
print strings
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be updated? You're specifically doing that inside `palinBreak`.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I have added that info too, please have a look!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that arr will be the same list in the inner recursive calls.
Try to replace

```
        pb = palinBreak(s, start+i, arr)
```

with

```
        pb = palinBreak(s, start+i, list(arr))
```

Comment: Output is: ans is ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'] ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b']
strings is ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', [...]]
ans is ['a', 'b', 'a', 'aa', 'b'] ['a', 'b', 'a', 'aa', 'b']
strings is ['a', 'b', 'a', 'aa', 'b', [...]]
ans is ['a', 'b', 'a', 'baab'] ['a', 'b', 'a', 'baab']
strings is ['a', 'b', 'a', 'baab', [...]]
ans is ['a', 'b', 'a', 'aba', 'a', 'b'] ['a', 'b', 'a', 'aba', 'a', 'b']
strings is ['a', 'b', 'a', 'aba', 'a', 'b', [...]]
['a', 'b', 'a', 'aba']

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean. I correct my answer.